# Hanging a TV above a wood stove?

Tags: fireplace, mounting, television, woodstove

I'm looking at hanging a TV above a wood stove for my family. There is a heat pipe that comes out of the top of the stove and into the wall. We would like to eliminate using a shelf but if it is necessary it's not a problem. My questions are, how far must a shelf be from that pipe according to code, and also how far away would the TV need to be from the shelf to prevent overheating and damage to the TV?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, code questions are off-topic here, and there's no way we can tell you whether your TV would be damaged by an unknown amount of heat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code questions are off-topic, and we can't know whether some TV could be damaged by some amount of heat.

Comment: your question makes no sense .... only you are in the position to determine how hot it gets above the stove

Comment: @DanielGriscom -- Code questions are not *necessarily* off-topic here

Comment: What type of flue/vent material are we talking about here?  Do you have the install manual for your wood stove, or a make/model # at least?

Comment: The pipe coming out the top is usually single wall until it comes to the ceiling/ wall box. This is to allow the heat to radiate and warm the room. You can change to a triple wall pipe but you still have the heat from the stove itself. This pipe can not be removed this is where the smoke exits the house.

Answer (score 3):

Code aside, the hottest thing in our living-room after the woodburner itself is the area directly above the wood-burner. I don't think this is a good place for any electronics, as most electronics generate heat of their own. Typically they dump these using heatsinks (large lumps of metal that quickly spread the heat over a wide area, like a radiator on a car or in your home), but these rely on the ambient temperature being relatively low. You'll find the electrical circuits in your TV will have a MUCH shorter lifespan - nevermind what it would do to the screen itself.

To be sure, check the manufacturer's recommendations for siting the telly and you'll probably find a safe operating temperature range. Compare this to the temperature of a thermometer hung where you want to hang your telly.

Answer (score 1):

The Code says that the WOOD STOVE needs to be U.L. Listed and that listing will have “clearances” listed. (ICC Chapter 21, 2111.14.)

I’d check with the manufacturer. If that’s not available I’d check with a similar sized unit.

Comment: You're going to find the TV manufacturer also lists numerous things to avoid. Such as location a television on a non rigid surface, near high heat sources, etc. You said you'd "like to mount a tv above a wood stove" but since heat rises, its not going to be a sensible practice. The warmer electronics are (generally) the lifespan shortens. Not to mention, while people do it all day long, TV's are suggested best positions at eye level center while seated, aka... 42". The recommendations you will see it to not do it.